# Tkinter Formatting DoubleVars for display

Tags: python, tkinter

I use `tk.DoubleVar()` to hold variables in my tkinter GUI.

However, if I am displaying percentages, as an example, I would like to display them as such.
For example

`0.05` -> `5%`

So I can format the fine, but using non-numeric characters(such as '%') then seems to cause an issue when I want to use `var.get()` because `5%` is not a valid numeric value.

Is there anyway to use variables, where the actual value is maintained, while allowing a formatted version of the value to be displayed?

Comment: Can you not create a new string to display? e.g. `"{}%".format(var.get()*100)`

Comment: Yeah I can format a string from the value however I want, but to make it display on the associated widget, I then have to do ```var.set()```. Then next time I use ```var.get()``` I get back the formatted version, not the actual version. It is a way around this problem that I am trying to figure out

Comment: don't set `var.set()` and keep original value. You can't get both - original value and formated string. And format it only when you need to display it. OR build own class which will have `get_string()` (or `__str__`) to get formated version.

Comment: @furas - i had considered subclassing as an option, but wanted to see if there was an obvious solution I was missing, but it seems not. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can convert value to string using

```
print( "{:.0}%".format(var.get()*100) )
```

or even using special formatting `{%}` and you don't need `*100` and `%`

```
print( "{:.0%}".format(var.get()) )
```

(I add `:.0` to display `5%` instead `5.00%`)

---

If you want to have both - value and formatted string - you could create class with method ie. `to_string()` to get it as string.

```
import tkinter as tk

class PercentVar(tk.DoubleVar):

    def to_string(self):
        return "{:.0%}".format(self.get())

# ---

root = tk.Tk()

myvar = PercentVar(value=0.05)

print('value:', myvar.get())
print('string:', myvar.to_string())
```

---

Or class may have method `__str__` to automatically convert string to formatted version when you `print()` it or use `str()` - but I don't know if `tkinter` doesn't uses normal value `PY_VAR0` to recognize object and using `__str__` can makes only problem.

```
import tkinter as tk

class PercentVar(tk.DoubleVar):

    def __str__(self):
        return "{:.0%}".format(self.get())

# ---

root = tk.Tk()

myvar = PercentVar(value=0.05)

print('value:', myvar.get())
print('string:', myvar)
print('string: ' + str(myvar))
print('string: {}'.format(myvar))
print(f'string: {myvar}')
```

---

To use it with widget it would use `trace`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- classes ---

class PercentVar(tk.DoubleVar):

    def to_string(self):
        return "{:.0%}".format(self.get())

# --- functions ---

def label_update(a, b, c):
    label["text"] = myvar.to_string()

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

myvar = PercentVar()

label = tk.Label(root)  # without text and textvariable
label.pack()

myvar.trace('w', label_update)  # run `label_update` when `myvar` change value 
myvar.set(0.05)  # set value after `trace`

root.mainloop()
```

But the same can be done using only `DoubleVar`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def label_update(a, b, c):
    label["text"] = "{:.0%}".format(myvar.get())

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

myvar = tk.DoubleVar()

label = tk.Label(root)  # without text and textvariable
label.pack()

myvar.trace('w', label_update)  # run `label_update` when `myvar` change value 
myvar.set(0.05)  # set value after `trace`

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** I made class `FormatLabel` which gets extra argument `format` at start  to format displayed text. But it has no function to changed it later with `config(format=...)` or `["format"] = ...`

Without `format` it works like normal `Label` (it uses format `'{}'`) but you can set i.e `fomat="{:.0%}"` to display `10%` instead `0.1`. You can even uses `format="Today: {:.0%} or more"` to display `"Today: 10% or more"`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- class ---

class FormatLabel(tk.Label):

    def __init__(self, master=None, cnf={}, **kw):

        # default values
        self._format = '{}'  
        self._textvariable = None

        # get new format and remove it from `kw` so later `super().__init__` doesn't use them (it would get error message)
        if 'format' in kw:
            self._format = kw['format']
            del kw['format']

        # get `textvariable` to assign own function which set formatted text in Label when variable change value
        if 'textvariable' in kw:
            self._textvariable = kw['textvariable']
            self._textvariable.trace('w', self._update_text)
            del kw['textvariable']

        # run `Label.__init__` without `format` and `textvariable`
        super().__init__(master, cnf={}, **kw)

        # update text after running `Label.__init__`
        if self._textvariable:
            #self._update_text(None, None, None)
            self._update_text(self._textvariable, '', 'w')

    def _update_text(self, a, b, c):
        """update text in label when variable change value"""
        self["text"] = self._format.format(self._textvariable.get())

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

myvar = tk.DoubleVar(value=0.05)

#label = FormatLabel(root, textvariable=myvar, format="Today: {:.0%} and growing")
label = FormatLabel(root, textvariable=myvar, format="{:.0%}")
label.pack()

myvar.set(0.1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank you. This is the sort of idea i was thinking of, but was having a few issues figuring out the details, but your example has made it v. clear. thanks

Comment: one issue with this I have realised. Its fine to print the values,as you show in your example, but if we associate the variable with a widget using ``textvariable=myvar`` then does the widget not use the ```get()``` method to display the value?

Comment: `get()` can't gives string in one situation and float in other situation. You will have to manually set value in widget - using ie. `label["text"] = myvar.to_string()`. Or you will have to use `myvar.tracer("w", callback)` to automatically execute own function `callback()` which will update widget. See [documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)

Comment: I added example with `trace`.

Comment: I add class `FormatLabel` which get `format="{:.0%}"` to display formatted text.