# digit grouping while typing in Python tkinter entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I would like to know is there anyway to group the numbers while typing in tkinter Entry widget?

For example if user entered 10000 entry widget shows 10,000? Just like what happens in windows calculator!

I've already gotten the entry in a Stringvar but I can not do `{:,}.format` on that stringvar. I think even a variable Label would be great for displaying digits in a grouped way.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tkinter Formatting DoubleVars for display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59408126/tkinter-formatting-doublevars-for-display)

Comment: No, that doesn't answer the question.  He's talking about tweaking an Entry widget on the fly.

Comment: You can do that by registering a callback.  https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-tkinter-validating-entry-widget/